# Some X apps accept my non-Latin characters, some ignore them

Tags: debian, keyboard-layout, xkb, hebrew, i18n

I'm using an X environment with a dual keyboard layout: `us,il`. Now, in some of my applications, and in the `il` layout, Hebrew characters don't register, while punctuation marks do. In other apps, Hebrew characters register just fine and are added to whatever text I'm typing. The English layout works fine.  I'll provide full details about my configuration below.

My questions are: Why is this happening? And more importantly, how can I fix/circumvent this and make all apps accept Hebrew characters as well?

#### Details about my setup

- **Physical Keyboard Layout:** Standard US 104-key (like [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_PC_keyboard#/media/File:Unicomp_keyboard.jpg)).
- **OS Distribution:** Devuan 2.0 ASCII (~= Debian 9.0 Stretch)
- **XKB configuration:**

  ```
  $ setxkbmap -query
  rules:      evdev
  model:      pc105
  layout:     us,il
  variant:    ,
  options:    grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll
  ```
- **Desktop Environment:** This happens to me with both Cinnamon and LXQt; haven't tried others yet.
- **Apps rejecting Hebrew characters:** Cinnamon's Alt+F2 launcher; LeafPad; GEdit, xterm.
- **Apps accepting Hebrew characters:** KWrite, GNOME Terminal, LibreOffice, Firefox, Kolourpaint, lxterminal, Konsole.

#### `xev` output

Output when pressing `a` on the keyboard:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x7e00001,
    root 0x43, subw 0x0, time 369470632, (96,-25), root:(146,62),
    state 0x0, keycode 38 (keysym 0x61, a), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (61) "a"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x7e00001,
    root 0x43, subw 0x0, time 369474392, (96,-25), root:(146,62),
    state 0x0, keycode 38 (keysym 0x61, a), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (61) "a"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Output when switching keyboard layout:

```
KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x7e00001,
    root 0x43, subw 0x0, time 369547896, (75,-23), root:(125,64),
    state 0x0, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x7e00001,
    root 0x43, subw 0x0, time 369548008, (75,-23), root:(125,64),
    state 0x8, keycode 62 (keysym 0xfe08, ISO_Next_Group), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 50
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

PropertyNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x7e00001,
    atom 0x176 (XKLAVIER_STATE), time 369548013, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x7e00001,
    atom 0x176 (XKLAVIER_STATE), time 369548013, state PropertyNewValue

KeyRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x7e00001,
    root 0x43, subw 0x0, time 369548072, (75,-23), root:(125,64),
    state 0x2008, keycode 62 (keysym 0xfe08, ISO_Next_Group), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 50
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x7e00001,
    root 0x43, subw 0x0, time 369548168, (75,-23), root:(125,64),
    state 0x2008, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Output when pressing `a` again on the Keyboard (this key also corresponds to the Hebrew letter shin, ש):

```
KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x7e00001,
    root 0x43, subw 0x0, time 369560440, (75,-23), root:(125,64),
    state 0x2000, keycode 38 (keysym 0xcf9, hebrew_shin), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x7e00001,
    root 0x43, subw 0x0, time 369560504, (75,-23), root:(125,64),
    state 0x2000, keycode 38 (keysym 0xcf9, hebrew_shin), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

#### `xmodmap -pke` output

Part of the output of `xmodmap -pke`:

```
... etc. etc. ...
keycode  24 = q Q slash Q U05C2
keycode  25 = w W apostrophe W U05C1
keycode  26 = e E hebrew_qoph E U05B8
keycode  27 = r R hebrew_resh R U05B3
keycode  28 = t T hebrew_aleph T
keycode  29 = y Y hebrew_tet Y U05F0
keycode  30 = u U hebrew_waw U U05B9
keycode  31 = i I hebrew_finalnun I
keycode  32 = o O hebrew_finalmem O
keycode  33 = p P hebrew_pe P U05B7
keycode  34 = bracketleft braceleft bracketright braceright U05B2
keycode  35 = bracketright braceright bracketleft braceleft U05BF
keycode  36 = Return NoSymbol Return
keycode  37 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L
keycode  38 = a A hebrew_shin A U05B0
keycode  39 = s S hebrew_dalet S U05BC
keycode  40 = d D hebrew_gimel D
keycode  41 = f F hebrew_kaph F
keycode  42 = g G hebrew_ayin G U05F1
keycode  43 = h H hebrew_yod H U05F2
keycode  44 = j J hebrew_chet J U05B4
keycode  45 = k K hebrew_lamed K
keycode  46 = l L hebrew_finalkaph L rightdoublequotemark
keycode  47 = semicolon colon hebrew_finalpe colon doublelowquotemark
keycode  48 = apostrophe quotedbl comma quotedbl U05F4
keycode  49 = grave asciitilde semicolon asciitilde U05F3
keycode  50 = Shift_L ISO_Next_Group Shift_L ISO_Next_Group
keycode  51 = backslash bar backslash bar U05BB
keycode  52 = z Z hebrew_zain Z
keycode  53 = x X hebrew_samech X U05B6
keycode  54 = c C hebrew_bet C U05B1
keycode  55 = v V hebrew_he V
keycode  56 = b B hebrew_nun B NoSymbol U05C6
keycode  57 = n N hebrew_mem N
keycode  58 = m M hebrew_zade M U05B5
keycode  59 = comma less hebrew_taw greater rightsinglequotemark
keycode  60 = period greater hebrew_finalzade less singlelowquotemark
keycode  61 = slash question period question division
... etc. etc. ...
```

#### Language-related environment variables

```
$ env | grep LANG
LANG=en_IL
GDM_LANG=en_US.utf8
LANGUAGE=en_IL:en
```

#### Other notes

- If I create a clean user account, that user does *not* experience this problem. So it must be some kind of user-specific setting.
- If I copy Hebrew text, I can paste it in the apps refusing Hebrew characters and it displays fine.
- I kept my home folder from a previous, non-Devuan, Linux installation (it was Linux Mint 18.3).

Comment: Try this minor change : `setxkbmap -option grp:switch,grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll us,il`.

Comment: @harrymc: 1. That doesn't work. 2. This seems to add, rather than replace, xkb options (checked with `setxkbmap -query`).

Comment: I don't know your Linux. Could you please add some more info about your keyboard layout? How are you entering these characters? What is your keyboard? Which fonts?

Comment: @harrymc: Physical keyboard layout: Added. "How are you entering these characters?" I press keys on my keyboard. "Which fonts?" All of them, it doesn't matter.

Comment: So the question is not about "accepting characters" (they copy&paste just fine), but about "accepting keypresses". First step is do run `xev` and find out as what keysyms/keycodes the Hebrew characters show up (please edit question). From your app list, KDE and Gnome apps work, while older apps like xterm don't. So the guess is that those apps just don't process the keysyms. Have you tried urxvt instead of xterm?

Comment: @dirkt: The last part of your comment is incorrect - Gnome apps _don't_ work.

Comment: @dirkt: Added the `xev` output. It seems like X is seeing the Hebrew characters just fine... maybe it's a gtk/Gnome thing?

Answer (score 1):

The answer below did not solve the poster's problem, but the discussion that
followed did finally point to it.

We both concluded that the cause of the problem was some difference between
Mint and Devuan that manifested itself when the poster copied his entire
home folder from one to the other.
A big hint was the fact that under the root user's profile,
the problem did not manifest.

The poster then examined the files in his home folder related to the
keyboard, and the result is to be found in his answer.

---

Your problem seems the same as in the post
[Terminal does not accept some typed-in unicode characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/362164/terminal-does-not-accept-some-typed-in-unicode-characters).

The workaround found in that post was to modify `.Xmodmap` and replace the keysymnames
by their Unicode hex codes.

In the above post, for the greek `ifonlyif` character, the poster replaced the line :

> keycode  58 = m M m M percent Greek_mu KP_1 KP_1 **ifonlyif**

by the line :

> keycode  58 = m M m M percent Greek_mu KP_1 KP_1 **U21D4**

Not having your environment, I guess that in your example, you should for keycode 38
replace the text `hebrew_shin` by U05E9 (or something similar).

If this works for you, you would need to do the same for all the Hebrew letters,
which will unfortunately be rather painful.
If you are lucky, the unicode hex code might already be mentioned
in Xmodmap so you may do it via some `sed` magic.

Comment: Clearly, I should not need to make user-specific changes - nor change anything manually. What I would need is the relevant files which, in other distributions (e.g. Ubuntu, Mint, Fedora), result in all apps accepting the appropriate characters. But +1 for your help so far.

Comment: Also, this suggestion doesn't seem to be applicable, since `xmodmap -pke | grep shin` gives me `keycode  38 = a A hebrew_shin A U05B0` already.

Comment: Strange : [U05B0](https://codepoints.net/U+05B0?lang=en) seems to be wrong. Shin should be [U05E9](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/05e9/index.htm). U05B0 is a vowel sign and has no display of its own. I wonder if this is your problem, that the Hebrew Xmodmap table is all screwed up in your distribution for this keyboard layout.

Comment: I'll try locating the relevant files (`/usr/share/xkb` maybe?) and compare them against another distro's.

Comment: So, `symbols/il` is the same for both distros. However, `U05B0` is not a vowel sign, it's the shva character modifier - which apparently you are supposed to get in the third level. The relevant symbols file line is: `key <AC01> { [ hebrew_shin, A,      U05B0   ]       };  // Shva`. Now, you could tell me "swap the `hebrew_shin` for `U05E9` - but that's not the "right way" to do it, because on Lubuntu it's not swapped like that. The problem is elsewhere; it's some kind of interpretation issue.

Comment: I got frustrated, so I installed Devuan in a VM and have no problem typing and using alt-shift to switch. Here is [proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGdpe.jpg). I used the command `setxkbmap -option grp:switch,grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll us,il`. Whatever other manipulations you did didn't help and should be undone.

Comment: Note : I used Devuan Ascii.

Comment: 1. You used a terminal. I did not have a problem typing in terminals. 2. I used my home folder from a previous distribution (Linux Mint 18.3). Can't quite undo that - unless I know what needs to be undone. But I can confirm that, with the root user's profile, the problem does not manifest.

Comment: I think we can conclude that the cause is some difference between Mint and Devuan that manifested when you copied your home folder. Maybe this is some file related to xmodmap in your home folder.

Comment: Some possibilities : `~/.Xmodmap`, `~/.xinitrc`, `~/.config/autostart/xmodmap.desktop`,`~/.bashrc` or `/etc/bash.bashrc`.  The following might help to debug: `sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep -B 5 -A 5 xmodmap`.

Comment: None of those, but you've inspired me to find the solution. See my new answer.

Answer (score 1):

#### You need to remove/clear your ~/.xinputrc file.

Inspired by some guess-work suggested by @harrymc, I've found the culprit: my `~/.xinputrc` file, generated on my previous distribution (Linux Mint 18.3). It says:

```
# im-config(8) generated on Wed, 25 Jan 2017 22:44:55 +0100
run_im xim
# im-config signature: 21f3e409b30c3de81e8302273ccb3d5c  -
```

The `im-config` mechanism is

> the input method on X Window System with GTK GUI or console terminal dialogue.

which explains why only (simpler) GTK apps seem to be affected. I'm not at all familiar with input-method business, but - if I remove this file, or comment-out the `run_im` option - all apps now seem to accept the Hebrew characters I type in.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

If you compare `a` and `ש`, you'll see

```
XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (61) "a"
```

vs.

```
XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
```

And that is the problem, because looking at the man page, [XLookupString](https://linux.die.net/man/3/xlookupstring) only handles Latin-1, so applications relying on XLookupString to translate the keypresses to characters will get an empty result, which causes your "Hebrew characters don't register, while punctuation marks do.".

And apparently some other applications, e.g. the KDE ones, work around this or use a different method.

I don't know how to fix this. You'll need to use applications that understand Unicode/UTF-8, and also translate the received keysyms properly. Patching the source code of non-working apps is an option, but if it was easy, I'm sure somebody would have already done this ... so I'd assume there are some gotchas.

Alternatives to `XLookupString` that work with UTF-8 ([Xutf8LookupString](https://linux.die.net/man/3/xmblookupstring)) do exist.

Comment: But this works with other distributions... and I _am_ using apps which understand Unicode.

Comment: When I try `xev` on Lubuntu 18.04, it says `XLookupString gives 2 bytes: (d7 a9) "ש"`.

Comment: Interesting. So that looks like there are two implementations: One that follows the man page and says it should only do latin-1, one that ignores that and gives utf-8 anyway. Which means the culprit are either different X libraries, or different xkbd files which cause XLookupString to act differently. So the next step should be looking at the source code of XLookupString of Devuan uses.

Comment: Maybe it's just compiled with the wrong flags or something?

Comment: No idea. The X build system is (or was, the last time I looked at it) quite complex. I'd build the packages from source for both Lubuntu and Devuan and take a good look at what happens if it was my problem, but that can easily consume quite a bit of time.